# FileVault optimizing... 43 days remaining

Tags: macos, filevault

My FileVault says that I have to wait for 43 days for it to finish optimizing something. As soon as I launch any application it stops working. So the only time that I can dedicate for the FileVault to finish optimizing is 8-12 hours of night which makes 43 days in reality 86 days. The readings are always jumping, one time you might see 3532 days remaining but never goes below 20 days.

On the other hand when working on battery it eats up my battery power of which I'm being informed by clicking on battery and looking through the list of "Apps using significant energy"

Maybe someone has stumbled upon this problem previously? How to speed things up, I can't wait for 3532 days for the optimization to complete that looks nonsense...

[image]

**EDIT**

Ok, I've waited for few days, here's how the picture is looking now:

[image]

I can't wait for 3526 days, that's almost 10 years by the way, so how do you speed things up?

**EDIT**

My disk drive capacity is 498 gigs, 68 gigs are unused, I have verified file system health with Disk Utility (did that in recovery mode)

**ANOTHER EDIT**

Now this is real shitty situation, I've waited for 133 days from the moment I've originally asked my question and it is not yet finished yet. I've counted pixels in the progress bar to count the value of progress that was made for these 133 days and it was 371 so this means that I have to wait for additional 86 pixels of the progress bar in order for the process to complete. Doing some elementary math I've figured out that it would take (statistically speaking) additional 30 days to complete the process. I would probably rephrase my original question: Just how stupid a software engineer should be in order to result with such piece of software?

BTW. I've free-up some space, so now I have 257.44 GB available

[image]

Comment: & your question is?

Comment: How to speed things up? :)

Comment: Pretty sure you'll just have to wait it out. Full disk might make it worse, but I'm not sure how much I'd want to be messing with it half way through that type of operation; last thing you want to do is break it.

Comment: 43 days looks unreal, if you will try counting the speed that it processes data with, it looks unreal, the total capacity of my drive is 498 gigs, 68 gigs are unused, 498-68 = 430 gigs to process, 430 / 43 = 10 gigs per day, 10 gigs per day is 10/24/60/60 * 1024 = 0.11 mb/sec, why does it work so slow? (I have SSD btw)

Comment: Please add within your original question (OQ) 1) how full is the partition or disk which you want to encrypt? 2) if you verified the file system health with `Disk Utility`?

Comment: 1) Capacity: 498.99 GB, Available: 257.44 GB
2) I have verified file system health with disk utility, everything is fine

Comment: Have you tried this step: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163448/my-system-seems-stuck-on-optimize-hard-drive-in-filevault

Comment: p.s. seems like a common issue but not to your extent!

Answer (score 1):

My wife bought a 11-inch MBA about a year ago. I turned on filevault as part of the setup, and had the same issue. We took it back to the apple store, and asked for a replacement citing the one she as being defective. In the stores, Apple isn't shady - we got a simple swap with smiles. The new one did FileVault2 just fine.

Everyone should do it exactly this way. As soon as you buy it, turn it on. Before you attempt to transfer any media/stuff to it or install apps. If it doesn't work, take it back to the Apple Store and ask for a replacement or a refund.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. After several back and forth my hard drive was replaced by Apple. 
Problems with FileVault could be a warning sign that you drive is dieing.